# iOS Json Get determined number of string the first two

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

Hellos a little blocked here I want to have a limited of string 
for example: only the first two values db_id 1 and 2

```
 {

    date = "12/01/2012";
    "db_id" = 1;
},
    {

    date = "10/01/2012";
    "db_id" = 2;

},
    {

    date = "09/12/2015";
    "db_id" = 3;

},
    {

    date = "10/12/2015";
    "db_id" = 4;

},



  NSString *requestString = @"url";
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *Array = [JSON valueForKey:@"moods"];
    NSLog(@"%@",Array);


for (NSMutableArray *result in Array)

{

    NSDictionary* Date = [result valueForKey:@"db_id"];
    NSLog(@"%@",Date );



}
```

This is my console In this case I have 10 string, but I'm only interested in the first 5

```
2015-12-17 10:34:21.978 App[5673:1609864] 1
2015-12-17 10:34:21.978 App[5673:1609864] 2
2015-12-17 10:34:21.978 App[5673:1609864] 3
2015-12-17 10:34:21.978 App[5673:1609864] 4
2015-12-17 10:34:21.979 App[5673:1609864] 5
2015-12-17 10:34:21.979 App[5673:1609864] 6
2015-12-17 10:34:21.979 App[5673:1609864] 7
2015-12-17 10:34:21.979 App[5673:1609864] 8
2015-12-17 10:34:21.980 App[5673:1609864] 9
2015-12-17 10:34:21.980 App[5673:1609864] 10
```

Comment: use a counter, start it with zero value and every iterate increase it by one and check if it reached 5 or not.

Comment: You can use `subarrayWithRange:`, or a `for` loop with a counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *result;
for (int i = 0 ; i < Array.count ; i++)
{

    NSDictionary* Date = [result valueForKey:@"db_id"];
    NSLog(@"%@",Date );

}
```